# Store a big array in the MySQL table

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create table`stops`for all stops with these columns `id, stop_name, stop_lat, stop_long, route,  arrivaltime` but I dont know how can I  store the `arrivaltime` into the table since this column is a big array

Like this:

```
{
   "id": 1
   "stops_name": "Amersham ",
   "arrival_time": {
                    "mon-fri": [ "05:38", "06:07","06:37",.....50 entries],
                    "sat": ["05:34","06:01","06:31",...........50 entries],
                    "son": ["06:02","06:34","07:04",...........50 entries]
                   },
    "stops_lat": 83.837994,
    "stops_long": 18.700423
 }
```

Is that to manage with mysql?

Comment: Which arrival time(s) do you want to return, and how? Could you add the arrival times in a separate table?

Comment: @Reisclef: the bus arrival times. From each stop should I create seperate arrival time table?

Comment: Perhaps I should have clarified: How do you intend on using the arrival times after you retrieve them from SQL?

Comment: I want to send the route number as return to the user if the user close to the stop and the arrivaltime reachs.

Comment: Data-wise, probably best to have the arrival time, and the related stop id as a foreign key for an Arrivals table. That's about the best advice that can be given with my understanding of what you want, based on that amount of detail.

Comment: @Reisclef: More datail; I am implementing Android app restful web services . For this app I need to create `stops` table in the mysql database with the folowing colmumns `id, long, lat, route`, `arrivaltime`, `name` so the app will every minute query the server to retrieve the route number from the  tabel  and depend on the rider position as well as the arrivaltime  popup windows will appear to ask the user whether the bus arrive the stop. was your advice the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally speaking you would split the "arrival times" out into a new table, referencing back to the table of stops.  You would also generally store each time as a single row, and then select the entire collection of rows.

This works best because it lets you query on the 'time' column and search for time ranges, etc and only get the relevant rows.

For the "day", I would most likely use a Set to have a column that can be 1 or more values.  Also consider that likely you may need to store info on public holidays or other special dates as well:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/set.html

Stops: id, stops_name, stops_lat, stops_long (1, "Amersham", 83.837994, 18.700423)
Stops_arrivals: id, stops_id, day, time (1, 1, "Mon", "05:38"), (2, 1, "Mon", "06:07"), etc